# div width should be equal to the body width

Tags: css

I am having a problem  with my CSS code. I want the div .top & .header equal to the width of the
body but it limits to the width of the container. I want it remain inside the container class.

Thanks,

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #000;
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 910px;
    height: 800px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: url(images/bg_home.jpg) no-repeat right;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 0;
}
.top {
    background: #00112b;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 49px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0.50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.header {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    background: #012e46;
    width: 100%;
    height: 99px;
    z-index: 2;
}
.header .login {
    background: red;
    opacity: 100;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    float: right;
}
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

html

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="top">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="header"> 
    <table  class="login">
          <tr>
            <td>-- Schedule an appointment --</td>
        </tr>
      </table> 
</div>
<div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.gif" width="204" height="120"/></div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML as well

Comment: The width of an element can be wider than its container, but it will be not visible though. Unless you're happy with a scroll bar.

Comment: can you http://jsfiddle.net/ please?

Comment: `body` is default'y set by `width:100%;`  you said `.top` and `.header' are within `.container` the .container is fixed to 910px then how it goes equal to body..?

Answer (score 1):

Your question also contains the answer.

> I want the div .top & .header equal to the width of the body

This could be achieved by having an attribute / property of `width: 100%;`

> but it limits to the width of the container

This is because the container is the parent of the child element. Which means the max width of the child element is the width of the parent.

> I want it remain inside the container class.

Which means, you'll have to give the container the property of `width: 100%`.

You can also solve this by using the overflow property, but I assume that is not what you'd like.
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

---

Which ofcourse means:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 800px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background: url(images/bg_home.jpg) no-repeat right;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

---

Also, not related to your question but to your CSS, you have a property of `background` which loads an image and not repeat.

Is this what you want or is it a pattern? In the last case, consider it making a small picture to repeat over the entire page, this reduces the load time of the webpage.

If the question was regarding your `background` not meeting the `body`s width, consider adding it to the `body` tag instead of the `container` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have given .top and .header a width of 100% - they sit inside the container div which has a width of 910px. Therefore by saying .top width 100% you are basically saying .top width 910px because it is a child of container therefore it will take on those styles.

Why do the .top and .header need to sit inside the container? If you would them to be 100% i.e. fill the whole browser window, then you should take them outside the container div.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Like this

please `remove` `width:100%;` for `below selector:`

**css**

```
.top {
    background: #00112b;

    position: relative;
    height: 49px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0.50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.header {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    background: #012e46;

    height: 99px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```